# On the equation $9x^3+y^3=z^2+3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The question is whether there exist integers $x,y,z$ such that
$$
9x^3+y^3=z^2+3.
$$
This is one of the nicest (if not the nicest one!) cubic equations for which I do not know whether integer solutions exist.

Heuristic argument predicts a lot of solutions, but the search returned no integer solutions up to $|z|\leq 50,000$. It seems that there must be a reason for this. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Possibly useful note for extending the search range: Mod 9 shows that $z \not \equiv 0\pmod{3}$, and one can use that to then show that $y \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: well, what about $9 x^3 + y^3 = z^2 + 3 w^2  $

Comment: Of course $9x^3+y^3=z^2+3w^2$ is solvable. The simplest solution is (0,0,0,0). Another example is (1,3,3,3).

Comment: Good.  Next restriction, with $\gcd(z,w) = 1.$   If this is difficult or impossible it may explain some things

Comment: The simplest solution to $9x^3+y^3=z^2+3w^2$ with last 2 variables coprime is (3,1,1,9). Or, if you like all variables pairwise coprime, (3,1,13,5).

Comment: ran a little program, lots of those...

Comment: Note that there are rational solutions, e.g. $(4,15,14)/9$, $(7,0,10)/9$, $(10,-9,26)/9$, $(17,-9,38)/18$, $(19,-15,79)/9$, $(-15,48,28)/27$, $(-13,39,35)/18$, $(-3,39,1)/27$, $(-2,27,44)/9$, $(-1,27,11)/18$, $(-53,129,299)/9$, etc. (Just with denominator $9$ one might wonder whether there are infinitely many solutions.)

Comment: (In my previous comment I'm referring to rational solutions of the OP's equation $9x^3+y^3=z^2+3$, not the follow-up equation proposed in the comments for whatever reason. Or equivalently integral solutions to the homogeneized equation $9x^3+y^3=z^2w+3w^3$, with $w\neq 0$. With denominator $9$ it thus refers to integral solutions of $9x^3+y^3=9z^2+27$.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This equation is unsolvable. Modulo 9 analysis shows that $z \ne 0 \pmod{3}$ and $z \ne \pm 1 \pmod{9}$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $z^2 + 3$ for which 3 is not a cubic residue. From
$$z^2 + 3 = 1/3(3y^3 - (-3x)^3)$$
it follows that $3 \mid \nu_p(z^2 + 3)$. But we will show that $z^2 + 3$ ($z \ne 0 \pmod{3}$ and $z \ne \pm 1 \pmod{9}$) always has prime divisor $q$ for which 3 is a cubic nonresidue and $\nu_q(z^2 + 3)$ is not divisible by 3.

The proof requires the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, $\omega = \frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
$$z^2 + 3 = (z + 1 + 2\omega)(z - 1 - 2\omega)$$
We can calculate cubic character using the cubic reciprocity law. Let $z \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, replace $z$ with $-z$ otherwise.
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \left(\frac{3}{z + 1 + 2\omega}\right)_3 = \left(\frac{3}{\omega(z + 1 + 2\omega)}\right)_3 = \\
        = \left(\frac{3}{-2 + (z - 1)\omega}\right)_3 = \omega^{1/3(z - 1)} \ne 1 \\
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Hence, $z + 1 + 2\omega$ has prime divisor $\pi$ such that 3 is a cubic nonresidue modulo $\pi$ and $\nu_{\pi} (z + 1 + 2\omega)$ is not divisible by 3. The same applies to complex conjugate $\overline{\pi} \mid z - 1 - 2\omega$. Thus, we can take $q = \pi \overline{\pi} \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: Can you say more about why $3$ being a cubic nonresidue mod $p$ implies that $3\mid \nu_p(z^2+3)$? I don't follow that step.

Comment: @TimothyChow If $y$ is not divisible by $p$, then $3 \equiv (\frac{-3x}{y})^3 \pmod{p}$ which is impossible. If $y \mid p$, then $x \mid p$. $9(x/p)^3 + (y/p)^3 = (z^2 + 3)/p^3$. We can continue this process until we get $9(x/p^k)^3 + (y/p^k)^3 = (z^2 + 3)/(p^{3k}) $ where $(z^2 + 3)/(p^{3k})$ is not divisible by $p$. Hence, $\nu_p(z^2 + 3) = 3k$.

Comment: A typo in second sentence: If $p \mid y$ then $p \mid x$.